# Scrollable and div with resizable from west side

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I need to make a navbar on the left and content on the right. What I have works well. But, when scrollbar appears on the navbar, resize icon stays about 7 pixels on the inside. If I can make content pane resizable and add the resize icon on west side then, the jquery will add hidden resize div on the content side, which will make resize icon appear right on resize border.

Currently without scrollbar, looks perfect.

[Image without Scrollbars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r8SC.png)

Now with the scrollbars:

[Image with the scrollbars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydTYt.png)

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #222;
        }

        #nav {
            float: left;
            border-width: 0 5px 0 0;
            border-style: solid;
            background-color: yellow;
            width: 10%;
            height: 100vh;
            max-height: 100%;
            overflow-x: auto;
        }

        #content {
            background-color: brown;
            width: auto;
            height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#nav').resizable({
                handles: 'e'
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="nav">This area should be scrollable and resizable with scrollbars on all the time.
    </div>
    <div id="content">content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I can make right side (content) resizable so that resize icon always be on resize bar, left side will have its scrollbars and both sides should resize as they do now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by attaching jquery resizable to "content". Also used the solution provided in [bugsdb](https://bugsdb.com/_en/debug/205a22489fadf5c1949aa1ac0400d691) which solves resizing navbar in reverse order.

```
   <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #222;
        }

        #main {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 150px auto;
            height:100vh;
        }

        #nav {
            border-width: 0 0 0 0;
            border-style: solid;
            background-color: yellow;
            min-height: 100vh;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
        #insidenav {
            min-width: 400px;
            background-color: blue;
        }
        #content {
            background-color: brown;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            //https://bugsdb.com/_en/debug/205a22489fadf5c1949aa1ac0400d691

            $.ui.plugin.add("resizable", "alsoResizeReverse", {

                start: function() {
                    var that = $(this).resizable( "instance" ),
                        o = that.options;

                    $(o.alsoResizeReverse).each(function() {
                        var el = $(this);
                        el.data("ui-resizable-alsoresizeReverse", {
                            width: parseInt(el.width(), 10), height: parseInt(el.height(), 10),
                            left: parseInt(el.css("left"), 10), top: parseInt(el.css("top"), 10)
                        });
                    });
                },

                resize: function(event, ui) {
                    var that = $(this).resizable( "instance" ),
                        o = that.options,
                        os = that.originalSize,
                        op = that.originalPosition,
                        delta = {
                            height: (that.size.height - os.height) || 0,
                            width: (that.size.width - os.width) || 0,
                            top: (that.position.top - op.top) || 0,
                            left: (that.position.left - op.left) || 0
                        };

                    $(o.alsoResizeReverse).each(function() {
                        var el = $(this), start = $(this).data("ui-resizable-alsoresize-reverse"), style = {},
                            css = el.parents(ui.originalElement[0]).length ?
                                [ "width", "height" ] :
                                [ "width", "height", "top", "left" ];

                        $.each(css, function(i, prop) {
                            var sum = (start[prop] || 0) - (delta[prop] || 0);
                            if (sum && sum >= 0) {
                                style[prop] = sum || null;
                            }
                        });

                        el.css(style);
                    });
                },

                stop: function() {
                    $(this).removeData("resizable-alsoresize-reverse");
                }
            });


            $('#content').resizable({
                handles: 'w',
                resize: function(event, ui) {
                }
            });

            $( "#content" ).resizable( "option", "alsoResizeReverse", "#nav" );

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <section id="nav">
            <div id="insidenav">
            This area should be scrollable and resizable with scrollbars on all the time.
        </div>
        </section>
        <section id="content">content
            <input type="button" id="winWidth" value="Width"/>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```